# Partial keys of wired keyboard are working upon boot up (works after unpluging & plugging back in)

Tags: boot, usb, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have https://shop.goldtouch.com/products/goldtouch-v2-adjustable-comfort-keyboard-pc-only keyboard (wired).

I never had an issue with this keyboard for years.

However suddenly, right hand side of this keyboard wasn't responding when the computer boots up (when I attempt to write passwords on log in page).

it works fine if I unplug the USB and replug it.

But after doing it so for months, I got sick of it and I would like to get this fixed.

I checked Legacy USB Support, it was set to Enabled.
I also have Windows installed on the same hardware (on different hard disk, I choose it Windows or Ubuntu upon boot up)

Can anyone tell me what I can try to fix this issue?

Comment: There was a sort of python driver written that detects keypresses from USB signals for the Goldtouch Bluetooth keyboard. Perhaps it does not suffer from the bug you describe it: https://github.com/a-t-0/Goldtouch_keyboard_driver disclaimer, I'm involved in developing the project.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn’t happen very often but, when it does, it can usually be resolved by installing the Hardware Enablement package and/or `xserver-xorg-input-all`.

After booting (and doing the unplug/replug action for your keyboard), open Termimal and type these commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-20.04 xserver-xorg-input-all
```

***Note:** If you are not running 20.04, be sure to change the HWE version to match the one you’re using.*

Once installed, reboot. Your USB keyboard should be properly functioning from that point onwards.